# How to sort a list within a list using sort in python?

Tags: python

I begin with a particular list, for example,

```
seq = [[10, 5, 8], [5, 8, 7], [8, 7, 9]]
```

And I want to sort it in a way that the list within a list gets sorted:

```
end_result = [[5, 8, 10], [5, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I know I can easily use a for loop:

```
for i in seq:
    i.sort()
```

But is there a direct way using sort with the key parameter?

Comment: do you know how to sort a single list? do you know how to iterate through items in a list? I see you've answered you do in an edit :)

Comment: You'll have to use a loop.  `result = [sorted[k] for k in seq]`

Comment: "But is there a direct way using sort with the key parameter?" no, using `sorted` *will sort the whole list* and shouldn't modify the elements inside the list. What youv'e shown is a reasonable way to do this

Comment: You could shorten it even a tiny bit more to `for i in seq: i.sort()` on one line, but I think you already have the best way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a direct way using sort with the key parameter?

No, using `sorted` *will sort the whole list* and shouldn't modify the elements inside the list. What you've shown is a reasonable way to do this.

*<sub>-- [comment](/questions/67844547/how-to-sort-a-list-within-a-list-using-sort-in-python#comment119917787_67844547) by [juanpa.arrivillaga](/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga), slightly modified</sub>*